# How to add a word vertically to a horizontal word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a board with one word in it for example, hippopotamus. I want to add a word to rattlesnake vertically (if the word has one of the same letters as the one on the board). For example, horse could be added to hippopotamus like this:
[image]

I have a checkVertical function which returns True if the word can be added vertically and False if it can't

```
    def printboard(board):

    print(' 01234567890123456789''\n'' ____________________')

    for i in range(20):
        print('|', end = '')
        for j in range(20):
            print(board[i][j], end = '')
        print('|', i)

    print(' ____________________''\n'' 01234567890123456789')



def addFirstWord(board, word): # Adds first word to the middle of the board

    indexRow = len(board)//2
    indexCol = (len(board) - len(word))//2
    if len(word) < len(board):
        for i in range(len(word)):
            board[indexRow][indexCol+i] = word[i]
        print(True)
    elif len(word) > len(board):
        print(False)

def checkvertical(board, word, row, col):

    #(a) the word is not too long for the board at that spot
    if len(word) > 20 - row:
        return False
    #(b) at least one letter of word must match
    #(c) other letters of word must land on blanks
    matchesoneletter = False

    for k in range(len(word)):
        wordletter = word[k]
        boardletter = board[row + k][col]
        #are these two letters the same?
        if wordletter == boardletter:
            matchesoneletter = True
        #is the boardletter a blank, if so continue
        if boardletter == blank:
            continue
        elif boardletter != wordletter:
            return False
        return matchesoneletter

def find(board, letter) : #Finds the first occurence of a letter on the board

    for i in range(len(board)) :
        for j in range(len(board)) :
            if board[i][j] == letter :
                return (i, j)
    return None

def addvertical(board, word) :
    # go across and down the whole board looking for a spot to add word
    for i in range(len(board)) :
        for j in range(len(board)) :
            # check if word can go at (i,j)  and if it can, then place it there
            if board[i][j] == 
    return False

word = 'hippopotamus'
addFirstWord(board, word)
printboard(board)

(rowo, colo) = find(board, 'o')
print(checkvertical(board, 'horse', rowo-1, colo))
addvertical(board, 'horse')
```

I'm stuck trying to check if the word can go at (i, j) and if it can, how to place it there

[edit]
I have made a checkhorizontal function and addhorizontal function
how can I implement a function addL(board, L) which accepts a list of strings and inputs them into the board.

```
def addwords(board, L):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if i == 0:
            addFirstWord(board, L[0])
        elif i % 2 == 0:
            addvertical(board, L[i])
        else:
            addhorizontal(board, L[i])
L = ['hippopotamus', 'horse', 'loon', 'cat', 'monster', 'rattlesnake', 'dinosaur']
addwords(board, L)
```

I have this so far where the first word in the list is added to the middle and then words are added horizontally and vertically alternately. The words aren't being outputted.

Comment: Please show how you're calling this and expected input/output. What does `board` look like? Thanks.

Comment: You can check the position of a letter and if it occures with the python function Index. You can use it for finding the position for the horizontal as well for the vertical. Here is a usefull link: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index

Comment: Check your code line number 36. I think you are missing something there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the use for the find() function but i think this should work

```
def checkVertical(board, word, row, col):
    D = len(board)
    n = len(word)
    blank = ' '
    if n>(20-row):
        return False
    matchesoneletter = False
    for k in range(n):
        wordletter = word[k]
        boardletter = board[row + k][col]
        if wordletter == boardletter:
            matchesoneletter = True
        if boardletter == blank:
            continue
        elif boardletter != wordletter:
            return False
    return matchesoneletter

def addVertical(board, word):
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board)):
            if checkVertical(board, word, i, j):
                for k in range(len(word)):
                    board[i + k][j] = word[k]
                return True 
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks this helped alot! Could you explain what if checkVertical(board, word, i, j): and board[i +k][j] = word[k] does

Comment: So the part where the for loop for "i" and "j" is just looping through every possible value of the entire 2-d matrix. For every one of those values, it puts those i and j values (row and column) in the checkVertical() function and checks if there is a matching letter. If that checkVertical() function ends up to be true, then it goes to the next part. In the next part, it loops through each index of the word you want to place vertically (k). It then takes the i and j (row/column) that we found earlier and depending on which index we are on in the word, it adds that letter to the board.

Comment: I made an edit could you help me fix the addwords(board, L) function

Comment: you are not printing anything after the addWords() function. You are just altering the board values. You will have to either call the printBoard() function inside the addWords() function or in the main program outside of the function. Either one should work

Comment: how would I modify checkvertical so that words cannot be added vertically if there is another vertical word beside it?

Comment: That's what i'm trying to figure out now.......I'm also in CPS109 heh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202955/discussion-between-peri-and-guy).